# changing text inside a div to negative html code using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, templates

I have this div:

```
<div class="signs" id="signs" onclick="toggle()">&#43;</div>
```

which displays the positive sign. when clicking on it, I want to change it to the negative sign with html code `&#8722;`:

```
function toggle() {
  var x = document.getElementById("signs");
  if (x.textContent === `&#43`) {
    x.textContent = `&#8722;`;
  } else {
    x.textContent = `&#43;`;
  }
}
```

But `toggle` function changes the positive sign to plain text `&#8722;` and not the negative sign! How can I achieve changing the positive to negative sign using javascript with my structure above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try

```js
        function toggle() {
            var x = document.getElementById("signs");
            if (x.textContent == `+`) {
                x.textContent = `-`;
            } else {
                x.textContent = `+`;
            }
        }
```

this?

Answer (score 2):

retrieve the entity code using `charCodeAt()`, then update the element via `.innerHTML`

```js
function toggle() {
  var x = document.getElementById("signs");
  var code = x.textContent.charCodeAt();
  if (code === 43) {
    x.innerHTML = `&#8722;`;
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = `&#43;`;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="signs" id="signs" onclick="toggle()">&#43;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function toggle() {
            var x = document.getElementById("signs").textContent;
            if (x == `+`) {
                x = `-`;
            } else {
                x = `+`;
            }
             document.getElementById("signs").innerHTML = x;  
        }
```

```html
    <div class="signs" id="signs" onclick="toggle()">+</div>
```